# Why is my UL disappearing when I animate its parent element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Disclaimer: I'm relatively new to jQuery and JavaScript. The openStatement() function below executes whenever it is determined that the #statementTab is not already open. If the code below isn't enough information, simply check out the source below.

Basically, the UL containing the various tabs flickers and disappears whenever the user opens the #statementTab. I'd like to fix this.

Source: http://www.cameronhermens.com/dbunkr/brochure.html

```html
// The openStatement function opens the statement tab when the user clicks 
<a id="openIt"> (if the statement tab isn't already open).
```

```javascript
function openStatement() {
    $('#explore').animate({width: '70%'}, '200');
    $('#statementTab').animate({width: '213px'}, '1000');
};
```

```html
// Here's the DIV.
<div id="explore" class="brochure">
  <ul id="brochureTab">
    <li><a href="welcome.html" >welcome</a></li>
    <li><a href="ourMission.html">our mission</a></li>
    <li><a href="whatIsdBunkr.html">what is dBunkr</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="statementTab">
  <a id="openIt">
    <img class="opaque left-5" src="images/rightArrow.jpg" height="10" width="6" alt="Expand the Statement tab">
    <span class="statementBar">Statements</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Any console errors? `animate()` takes a number as the `speed` parameter, not a string from what I can tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `UL#brochureTab` is being hidden during animation because as `#explore` is animating, the jQuery is applying a style of `overflow: hidden` to it. This style is then removed upon completion of the animation.

A quick solution (i.e. without addressing the way that you have styled the rest of your elements) would be to add the style `overflow: visible !important;` to `#explore`.

Answer (score 1):

You have the `ul#brochureTab` outside the `div#explore` by using the CSS `top: -45px;`.

Whenever you animate the `div#explore` with jQuery .animate(), the `ul#brochureTab` gets "flashed" because the jQuery [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) automatic switches to `overflow:"hidden"` while performing the animation.

The solution is to use a `DIV` to serve as a wrapper to the `div#explore`, and have it with the visual look you've got on the `div#explore`:

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 3px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #CCCCCC;
    float: left;
    height: inherit;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

**THE MARKUP WOULD BE:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="explorer">
    <ul id="brochureTab">
      <li>...</li>
      <li>...</li>
      <li>...</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="ui-tabs-3">...</div>
    <div id="ui-tabs-10">...</div>
    <div id="ui-tabs-12">...</div>
  </div>
  <div id="statementTab">...</div>
</div>
```

**AND TO PREVENT THE FLASHING:**

```
#brochureTab {
  float: left;
  left: 10px;
  list-style: none outside none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  /* top: -45px; remove this line */
}

.ui-tabs-panel {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
  border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
  float: left;
  left: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto 30px;
  min-height: 410px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  /* top: -20px; remove this line */
  width: 90%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

To your current animation method, no changes need to be made.

To your new `CSS` for the wrapper, may require some "tunning".